# How to do LEFT OUTER JOIN with include

Tags: sequelize.js

For Model `A` and `B` with certain association, the following query create an `INNER JOIN`

```
A.findAll({include:[{model:B}], where:{...}})
```

The created SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON ...
```

How to generate `LEFT JOIN` with `include` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `required` to `false`

```
A.findAll({include:[{model:B, required: false}]})
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3936#issuecomment-112082519

Comment: With `where` present, default is `required:true` according to the doc about eager loading  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html